# Center drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navbar

I am trying to create a simple (seemingly simple!) centered horizontal menu that has centered dropdowns, both text align wise and centered under the parent.  Ideally I would like the dropdown menu the same width as the parent but that might be one step too far!

```css
nav {
  font-family: "bell mt";
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
  float: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li {
  float: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #3c3c3b;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #a7cc74;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 255px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li ul li {
  margin: 0;
  width: 255px;
}
nav ul li ul.sub-menu li a,
nav ul li ul li a:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: #3c3c3b;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li ul li:hover a {
  background: #fff;
  color: #a7cc74;
}
nav ul li ul.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999
}
nav ul li:hover ul.sub-menu {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu-main-menu-container">
  <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-6"><a href="#">THE HOLIDAY VILLAS</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-91" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-91"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/casa-delle-querce/">CASA DELLE QUERCE</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-90" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-90"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/frontone-holiday-villa/">FRONTONE</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-89" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-89"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/montevecchio-holiday-villa/">MONTEVECCHIO</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-45"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/how-to-get-there/">HOW TO GET THERE</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-97" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-97"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/gallery/">GALLERY</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-7" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-7"><a href="#">DISCOVER ITALY</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-72" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-72"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/about-the-area/">ABOUT THE AREA</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-88"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/eating-and-drinking-in-frontone/">EATING OUT</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-87" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-87"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/things-to-do/">THINGS TO DO</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-98" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-98"><a href="#">AVAILABILTY &amp; PRICING</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-37" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-37"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/availability-and-pricing/">AVAILABILTY &amp; PRICING</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-96" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-96"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/testimonials/">TESTIMONIALS</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-52"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/contact-us/">CONTACT US</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

*more detailed view also available at  http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/*

So, as you can see, I have the horizontal main bit of the menu centered ok, and I have the text-align on the dropdowns ok, **it is just they are not falling underneath the parent correctly.**

Comment: Please post your HTML, helps those trying to help you.

Comment: Always remember to accept the best answer and upvote those which helped you. It's rude not do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change**

```
nav ul li:hover ul.sub-menu {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

to

```
nav ul li:hover ul.sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

**In addition to above,**

I have given top level list items in the navbar a width of 255px that is, same as that of the drop-down menu.

*I have also added extra borders so that you can see the alignment, they serve no real purpose and should be ignored.*

*"center" is not a valid value for `float` property.*

**DEMO:**

```css
nav {
  font-family: "bell mt";
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
  /*float:center*/
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li {
  /*float:center*/
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: solid; /*it's there so that changes are visible, ignore*/
  width: 255px; /*same width for dropdown item and dropdown menu list*/
}
nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #3c3c3b;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #a7cc74;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 255px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li ul li {
  margin: 0;
  width: 255px;
}
nav ul li ul.sub-menu li a,
nav ul li ul li a:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: #3c3c3b;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li ul li:hover a {
  background: #fff;
  color: #a7cc74;
}
nav ul li ul.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999
}
nav ul li:hover ul.sub-menu {
  display: block;
  margin-left: -3px; /* adjusts for the border, ignore*/
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu-main-menu-container">
  <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-6"><a href="#">THE HOLIDAY VILLAS</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-91" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-91"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/casa-delle-querce/">CASA DELLE QUERCE</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-90" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-90"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/frontone-holiday-villa/">FRONTONE</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-89" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-89"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/montevecchio-holiday-villa/">MONTEVECCHIO</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-45"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/how-to-get-there/">HOW TO GET THERE</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-97" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-97"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/gallery/">GALLERY</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-7" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-7"><a href="#">DISCOVER ITALY</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-72" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-72"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/about-the-area/">ABOUT THE AREA</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-88"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/eating-and-drinking-in-frontone/">EATING OUT</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-87" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-87"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/things-to-do/">THINGS TO DO</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-98" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-98"><a href="#">AVAILABILTY &amp; PRICING</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-37" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-37"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/availability-and-pricing/">AVAILABILTY &amp; PRICING</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-96" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-96"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/testimonials/">TESTIMONIALS</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-52"><a href="http://79.170.44.75/casadellequerce.com/contact-us/">CONTACT US</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Add `position:relative` to parent `li` tag and `position:absolute;left:0;` assign to child `ul`

Answer (score 0):

Replace this bit of code with your

```
nav ul li:hover ul.sub-menu{
  display: -webkit-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your float:center.

Give your 
nav ul li a position:relative

```
nav ul li {
  ...
  position:relative
}
```

and

```
nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

So this way you're giving your main navigation list items an relative position. And you got them already centered.

Inside your main navigation list items you have your submenu ul . This needs an absolute position with left 0. So its inside the relative container and its position is then exactly lined up with the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add position relative to your li

```
    nav ul li {
  float: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

To your position absolute ul you need to give it a left position example below:

```
nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 255px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0px;
}
```

**Additional**

```
Float: center
```

Does not work - please remove

Answer (score 0):

This would be your CSS:

```
nav {
    font-family: "bell mt";
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
    float: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li a, nav ul li a:visited {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color: #3c3c3b;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #a7cc74;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 255px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul li ul li {
    margin: 0;
    width: 255px;
}
nav ul li ul.sub-menu li a, nav ul li ul li a:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
    color: #3c3c3b;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul li ul li:hover a {
    background: #fff;
    color: #a7cc74;
}
nav ul li ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    z-index: 9999
}
nav ul li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Note the following changes:

Your 'nav ul li' lost it's float: center and has gained position: relative, to make the position absolute of the child ul work.

The child ul has gained a left: 0; and right: 0; property, so the browser will center it automatically. And it gained a width: 100% to make it wide enough.

Answer (score 0):

`nav ul li {` - Add position relative here.

Also,  float: center; is wrong. Give `float: left;`

`nav ul li ul {` - Here `left` is missing. Give `left:0;`

Answer (score 0):

Remove all occurrences of

```
float:center
width:255px
```

Add to your css

```
nav ul li { position: relative; }
nav ul li ul { left: 0; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ugLm09e8/

---

**EDIT:**
Add following to avoid stacking of submenu items when you have very long headers

```
nav ul li ul li { display:block; }
nav ul li ul.sub-menu { width:100%; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ugLm09e8/2/